# Best way to use acts_as_tenant with blueprinter gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-tenant

I am loving using the [blueprinter](https://github.com/procore/blueprinter) gem for my API, but i'm finding using it with the [acts_as_tenant](https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant) gem kinda cumbersome with associations.  I have to pass in the account as options, which gets annoying when you have more than one association or nested associations.  Is there an easier way?

```
class UserBlueprint < Blueprinter::Base
  fields :uuid, :name, :plan

  association :posts, blueprint: PostBlueprint do |user, options|
    ActsAsTenant.with_tenant(options[:account]) do
      user.posts
    end
  end
end
```